# Graphql Storefront Shopify API fast dynamic filtration

Tags: graphql, shopify, storefront

I filter products by color, size, vendor etc.

I would like to query available filters and display filter count dynamically based on remaining products after filtration. Solution based on ReactJS works too slow with 50.000+ products and I need GraphQL solution. I found [example](https://shopify.dev/api/examples/filter-products#query-available-filters) how to query available filters by collection handle. But nothing similar to behaviour I described above.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?